# Is it possible to determine if any parent is disabled without jQuery?

Tags: javascript

Considering HTML like:

```
<button disabled='true'>
  <span class='one'>
    <span class='two'>
      Click me
    </span>
  </span>
</button>
```

and

```
el = document.querySelector('.two');
```

Is there a way to determine that el is disabled without using jQuery or iterating through all the parents?

Comment: Please clarify: your title says "any parent is disabled" but your question says "el is disabled".  Which is it?

Comment: JQuery is just JavaScript. It's not needed to solve ***any*** problem. It's also important that you understand that just because you don't write a loop when you use JQuery, doesn't mean that JQuery isn't performing one in the background.

Comment: If you don't want to iterate on the parent nodes how would you expect to be able to find out anything about them?

Comment: You could use a CSS selector.  `button[disabled]  .two`, or something to that effect.  No loop needed.  If the selector finds an element, it's disabled.

Comment: Amy, i think you mean't `button[disabled] .two`

Comment: @bukharim96 Yes I did, already corrected.  I always get the descendant selectors backwards in my mind.

Comment: @bukharim96 "cool story bro" with strangers is generally considered rude, also, referring to a woman as "bro" is also considered rude.

Comment: My bad, no offence intended.

Comment: You can definitely avoid jQuery.   But it is pretty hard to beat the following jQuery for simplicity and maintainability.  This will tell you if an element or any of its parents is disabled.   $('.two').is(':disabled')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to check if an element (or any of its parents) are disabled. Both involve using the css method of checking for an attribute.

The first is to use the `.closest()` method in a second command ([MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest))

```
var el = document.querySelector('.two');
if(el.closest('[disabled=true]')!=null) console.log("it's disabled");
```

The second can be done in one line, but you have to check two separate css conditions (separated by a comma):

```
var el2 = document.querySelector('[disabled=true] .two, .two[disabled=true]');
if(el2!=null) console.log("it's disabled");
```

With this method, first you're checking to see if it has a parent which is disabled. Second you have to check to see if the item itself is disabled.